# "of that" vs "of which"? word "chief" can refer to more than one item in a set?

Tags: grammar

> Since the last time I messaged you, there have been a number of new developments in my life, chief of which being graduating from college and getting my own place.

Can I say "chief of that being"? Or "chief thereof being"?

What's the difference between "of that" and "of which"?

And is **chief** only used to refer to one item in a set, or can it be used to refer to two like I did above (graduating college, and getting own place)?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use *chief of that being*. Although *that* and *which* are interchangeable in many contexts, after a preposition is one in which they are not.

[This is one of the principal reasons why that *that* is no longer regarded by grammarians as a relative pronoun, but as the same subordinator as in *He said that they had gone*. The argument is that the underlying form of the relative clause is *which that*, but in modern English at least one of these must be deleted.]

*Chief thereof being* is possible, but very literary.

To my ear, using *chief* like that does lead the listener to expect a single item: in that context, I read "graduating from college and getting my own place" as a single item. If the two parts were not closely connected, I don't think it would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use *that* you are confusing the subject of the sentence, and using something that refers to a singular object rather than plural objects.

There has been more than one development. If you refer back to that, you need to use *them*, not *that*:

> Since the last time I messaged you, there have been a number of **new developments** in my life, chief of **them** being graduating from college and getting my own place.

---

Note that neither *was* nor *were* follows *chief of them*. If one or the other did, you would be explicitly stating you are referring to one development or two developments.

Although *chief* normally refers to a single thing, it doesn't always have to. It's similar to *best*, where two or more items can, jointly, be considered the best:

> John and Sally **were** the best **students** in their class.

With [chief](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chief):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2** : of greatest importance or influence
>     // the *chief* reasons
>     // their *chief* accomplishment

The first example sentence has multiple reasons that are chief. The second has a single accomplishment that is chief.

In the sentence from the question, it's possible that *graduating from college and getting my own place* is considered as a single conceptual item. For instance, depending on how it's viewed, *washing and drying my clothes* can be one overall action or two discrete actions.

Comment: I think you are misparsing, Jason. I see the phrase _the chief of them being X_: _being graduating_ isn't a constituent (though I allow that it is awkward). _Being_ is not required there, as you say, but it is permitted.

Comment: Jason. Consider "the chief of them being 1) the amazing books I read while studying, 2) graduating from college, and 3) getting my own place. _Being graduation_ is a chance juxtaposition of syntactically independent verbs.

Comment: @ColinFine Ah, I see what you mean now, and you're right. I have removed my reference to that part of the sentence. (Although, normally, I would rephrase it to avoid the kind of parsing error I fell into.)